# The application “RStudio” is not open anymore

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to open Rstudio and I'm receiving the errror: The application “RStudio” is not open anymore. Before receiving this error, when it was open and running, I noticed there were two Rstudio icons in the dock. I've deleted the previous version of this program to try and resolve this problem in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/

I now only have version 3.3. Is it possible I still have another version of Rstudio on my computer somewhere or is this some other problem?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually uninstall the other version?

Comment: Dragged it to the trash..

Comment: I have a mac though

Answer (score 0):

> I now only have version 3.3

This is not true if all you did was to undock/remove the other version of RStudio.  If you want to completely *remove* the other version, you should actually uninstall the other version.  Go to:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework

delete the R application from "the Applications" folder (already done)
```

Keep in mind this might not fix the problem, but this will at least do what you thought was being done.

Reference: http://nemo-notes.blogspot.sg/2013/05/uninstall-r-from-mac-os-x.html

Comment: OP is using a Mac, from the sound of it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a general issue (which may be fixed by a reboot) but if you want to start another copy of any app on Mac OSX then you can do it this way from the terminal, using the `open` command (`-n` allows for another instance of the app to run, and `-a` chooses the specific app to launch):

```
open -n -a RStudio.app
```